# Twilio Functions Dependency - Use Private Node module

Tags: node.js, twilio

How can i include private npm package as my dependency module in Twilio functions. I have a node module in AWS CodeArtifcate which requires
npm run co:login
aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository {REPO_NAME} --domain {DOMAIN_NAME}

While i include a private module i am getting

Some dependencies could not be validated. Failed to find the @scope/module_name package.

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution. To improve this question, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - then edit your question. Show what you got, what you aim for, and what you get and make clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not currently have a way of connecting npm installs to private registries which is leading to your error message.

The current solution for including private code would be to use [private assets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api/api/understanding-visibility-public-private-and-protected-functions-and-assets) and [load the dependency using `require(Runtime.getAssets()[PATH])`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/client#runtimegetassets).